# Асинхронная загрузка файлов на хостинг телеграм бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, асинхронность, dropbox

Реализовал загрузку файлов на дропбокс через тг бота, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что на время загрузки файла на хост остальной функционал бота не работает. Бот просто не реагирует, пока не загрузится файл.

Можете предложить какие-нибудь варианты решения или может быть есть асинхронная библиотека какого-либо файлхостинга?

```
                    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(config.dropboxtoken)
                async with aiofiles.open(f'{file_path}', 'rb') as file:
                    response = dbx.files_upload(await file.read(),
                                                f'/{filename}')
                    await file.close()
                    print(response)
                url = dbx.files_get_temporary_link(f'/{filename}').link
                await message.answer(f'<a href="{url}">Ссылка</a>, parse_mode='HTML')
```

Comment: Как вариант: Загружать файлы в облако не в основном потоке, а запускать отдельный скрипт который загрузит и отправит URL на файл в тг.

Answer (score 1):

Реализовал загрузку на яндекс диск.
Использовал - [Библиотека-клиент REST API Яндекс.Диска (yadisk-async)](https://github.com/ivknv/yadisk-async).

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).